# Can we access the response of a request inside asyncThunk without selector and without passing by store or state in redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I'm wondering if there is a possibility In redux toolkit to access request response of an asyncThunk without passing by store or state or selector.
Sometimes we wanna use the data received from a request to perform another request.
So can we get the response request without waiting for state or store to update and without using useEffect.

I mean using response received from the asyncThunk in another request something like that:
const {id} = await dispatch(getTest())

dispatch (getTestResultById(id))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the first action is an asynchronous action/thunk then it can be awaited. Redux Toolkit thunks ***always*** resolve, so be sure to unwrap the returned resolved Promise to see if the action was successful or not.

Example:

```js
const handler = async () => {
  try {
    const { id } = await dispatch(getTest()).unwrap();

    dispatch (getTestResultById(id));
  } catch(error) {
    // handle rejected Promise or any thrown exceptions
  }
};
```

For more details see [Handling Thunk Results](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-results).